# Limit for posting comments

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying for a couple of days now to limit the amount of comments that can be posted by a user.
So after the user submits a comment he should wait for example 5 minutes, to be able to post the next comment.

I know that this can be accomplished by the laravel validator with the 'after' rule. But I've tried a couple of things now and nothing worked out yet.
Here's the Code of the method:

```
public function storeComment($id, Request $request)
{
  $user = User::with('newsComment')->find(Auth::user()->id);

  if ($user->NewsComment->count() != 0)
  {
    $last_comment = NewsComment::where('author_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $date_after = new \DateTime($last_comment->created_at);
    $date_after->modify('+5 minutes');

  } else {
    $date_after = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 00, 00, 0000));
  }

  $request->current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

  $this->validate($request, [
    'comment' => 'required|max:255|min:5',
    'current_date' => 'after:'.$date_after->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
  ]);



  $comment = new NewsComment;
  $comment->news_article_id = $id;
  $comment->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
  $comment->comment = $request->comment;
  $comment->save();
  return $this->showArticle($id);
}
```

So, I know, that this code reads the correct time out of the database and adds the 5 minutes to the given date. In the template I added an empty, hidden form field named 'current_date'. In the method above I fill this variable with the current date and try to validate it with the 'after' validation rule.

But for some reason it won't work.

I hope some of you can help me with this.

I'm btw new to laravel so please bear with me.

Comment: Do you know how to use regular php, without laravel?

Comment: It's about 2 years ago but I do, yes.

Comment: In the comments table, you have the date, and time column right? When they are trying to comment, check their last time when they commented. If it's less than 5 minutes ago, don't let them comment again.

Comment: No. I just have one column. The 'created_at' column. As you can see in the code, I take the date of the last comment, add 5 minutes and give this to the 'after' validation rule. So normally this should work out. Maybe I'm using the validator of laravel wrong. But I couldn't find a lot of information about the 'after' validation rule by googling.

Comment: Try doing it without laravel.

Comment: I'm sure this wouldn't be a problem with plain php. I just really want to use the classes laravel provides to keep it all clean. I know that I can write a validation rule myself but the 'after' normally should do the job. I just don't know why it doesn't in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$comment->save();` you can check if the comment is saved and flash in the Session the current timestamp then compare with "Now" after the validation.

```
if($comment->save()){
  $request->session()->put('post_time', Carbon::now());
}
```

and after validation:

```
if ($request->session()->has('post_time')) {
    if(Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($request->session()->get('post_time')) < 5){
        //stop execution
   }  

}
```